# How to select items with respect to date only in sqlite

Tags: c#, sqlite, datetime

I have to select all rows from database by just passing date. For example to get all rows that have date 11/9/2016

In sqlite db I store this in DATETIME column:

```
11/9/2016 6:44:46 PM
```

I have tried to get by using date() but I get nothing for date:

```
sql = "SELECT * FROM Tble_UserSetUp inner join Tble_Login on Tble_UserSetUp.Id = Tble_Login.UserId WHERE Tble_Login.UserId='" + UserID + "' and Tble_Login.LogInTime = date('" + AccessDate + "') or Tble_Login.LogOutTime = date('" + AccessDate + "')";
```

So all I need is to compare only dates but can't find how to do this in sqlite.

Comment: This is not one of the [supported date formats](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/sqlite/5252/data-types/18688/date-time-types).

Comment: https://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html#date_and_time_datatype

Answer (score 1, accepted):

refering to the [sqlite date documentation](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html) you have to use following format

```
YYYY-MM-DD
```

so AccessDate should be

```
AccessDate = "2016-11-09"
```

Comment: Hello, I have tried. But don't happening. Still it return null data.

Comment: Ok. Do you have tried to use the `datetime(...)` function?

Comment: It is not enough to change the query; the data in the database must have the correct format.

Comment: @DominikHerold Yes I have also did that but not happening? How can I do this?

Comment: @CL.How can I do this?

Comment: did you use the right format. Please try this 
`datetime(...)   strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S', ...) ` and
`Time Strings

A time string can be in any of the following formats:

    YYYY-MM-DD
    YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM
    YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS
    YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS.SSS
    YYYY-MM-DDTHH:MM
    YYYY-MM-DDTHH:MM:SS
    YYYY-MM-DDTHH:MM:SS.SSS
    HH:MM
    HH:MM:SS
    HH:MM:SS.SSS
    now
    DDDDDDDDDD `

[docu](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html)

I think for more help you need to post your sql DB schema, to check the types of the columns